# Using PHP to post an XML buffer to an HTTPS page

Tags: php, xml, post, curl, https

I am using php 5.2.9
I have an XML buffer which I need to post to some HTTPS URL.

What is the correct way of doing that?
I see various examples on the web, and none of them seem to be working for me:
Some define the cURL headers like so:

```
$headers = array(
        "POST " . $page . " HTTP/1.0",
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($buffer),
    );
```

Where $page holds the request on the server and $buffer contains the XML data.

The actual $buffer is sent as the value as:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $buffer);
```

But I don't see how this can work, as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS expects its value to be an array and not a buffer.

Then I saw several ways of configuring the SSL aspects of the call:

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
Are all of these needed? I saw examples where the following was also set:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

Can someone post a complete working example that explains what needs to be done in order to post an XML buffer using cURL to an HTTP URL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Don't specify the request method with the other headers. Use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for that.
- To send the data you have two options. You can either implement a stream wrapper that reads from `$buffer` that you then open with `fopen` and give as a `CURLOPT_INFILE` option (of course, if the XML is on disk, you can open it directly with `fopen`), or, more simply, you define a `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` callback.
- The verify peer part is only necessary if you want to check the validity of the server's certificate (you ought to).
- Basic authentication is necessary if the server requires basic authentication. Only you can know that.

Comment: I already the XML buffer in the $buffer variables. I don't want to have the code read it from the the disk. According to the callback solution, this is the what the function should look like:
string read_callback (resource ch, resource fd, long length)
where fd is the file descriptor passed to CURL by CURLOPT_INFILE option. Once again, I don't want to work with files. 
Isn't there a more simple solution?

Comment: @jason What the docs say is "The name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, and the second is a string with the data to be read. The data must be read by using this callback function. Return the number of bytes read. Return 0 to signal EOF." So no fd.